# Pyspark Dataframe Filter Condition with boolean and String in & Clause

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a very basic Dataframe filter requirement where i need to put 2 filter conditions. Here is my dataframe-

```
sqlContext.createDataFrame([('1000000','ABCD','20190516'),('1000000','ABCD','20190516'),('1000000','ABCD','20120516'),('5000000','WXYZ','20110516'),('2000000','PQRS','20140516'),('3000000','PQRS','20160516'),('3000000','PQRS','20150516')],['hashVal','prodCode','date'])
>>> df.show()
+-------+--------+--------+
|hashVal|prodCode|    date|
+-------+--------+--------+
|1000000|    ABCD|20190516|
|1000000|    ABCD|20190516|
|1000000|    ABCD|20120516|
|5000000|    WXYZ|20110516|
|2000000|    PQRS|20140516|
|3000000|    PQRS|20160516|
|3000000|    PQRS|20150516|
+-------+--------+--------+
```

The requirement is-

1. I need all the distinct records from this Dataframe if prodCode is in ("ABCD","WXYZ")
2. If prodCode is not in any of these 2 values ("ABCD","WXYZ"), then i only need distinct records which are >"20140516"

So desired out is -

```
+-------+--------+--------+
|hashVal|prodCode|    date|
+-------+--------+--------+
|1000000|    ABCD|20120516|
|5000000|    WXYZ|20110516|
|1000000|    ABCD|20190516|
|3000000|    PQRS|20160516|
|3000000|    PQRS|20150516|
+-------+--------+--------+
```

If i try with below code-

```
df.where(( col("prodCode").isin (["ABCD","WXYZ"])) | (  ~( col("prodCode").isin(["ABCD","WXYZ"])) & col("date")>"20140516"  ) ).distinct()
```

It gives me the error-

> u"cannot resolve '(NOT prodCode IN (ABCD,WXYZ) && date)' due to data type mismatch: differing types in '(NOT prodCode IN (ABCD,WXYZ) && date)' (boolean and string).;"

I do get the correct solution if i just break it 2 two conditions, however with this solution, i have to perform a Union which i am looking to avoid.

```
dfA = df.where( ( col("prodCode").isin (["ABCD","WXYZ"])) ).distinct()
dfB = df.where(~( col("prodCode").isin (["ABCD","WXYZ"])) ).where(col("date")>"20140516").distinct()
dfF = dfA.unionAll(dfB)
```

How can i make it work without having to split My dataframe with 2 different conditions and then merge again?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a parentheses around the condition. If there is more than one condition, each of them should be parenthesized. Also, one of the conditions here includes an `AND` within it. Make sure the individual conditions are separated by parentheses as well, to get the desired results. `A OR B AND C` gives a different result compared `A OR (B AND C)`.

Having said that, your condition should be

```
df.where((col("prodCode").isin (["ABCD","WXYZ"])) | ((~(col("prodCode").isin(["ABCD","WXYZ"]))) & (col("date")>"20140516"))).distinct()
```

Comment: Thanks Vamsi, one of those silly misses every now and then